# Why github ask username and password when to git push files in /var/www/html?

Tags: git, authentication, passwords

I set username and password in `.netrc`.

```
cat .netrc
machine github.com  
    login  myname  
    password mypassword
```

1. git push files in `/tmp` directory:
   Create a new repo `test-tmp` for this push in github's webpage.

```
    sudo cp  -R /var/www/html/cal  /tmp    
    sudo chown -R  debian.debian  /tmp/cal    
    cd  /tmp/cal    
    git init  
    git add  * 
    git commit -m "Add file"    
    git remote add origin https://github.com/gitsnippet/test-tmp.git       
    git push origin master
```

Github ask no username and password,`git push` succeed.

2. git push files in `/var/www/html/cal` directory:
   Create a new repo `test-var` for this push in github's webpage.
   Notice: All the `sudo` can't omit, for files in `/var/www/html`, git command without `sudo` result in such error as

   > error: could not lock config file `/var/www/html/cal/.git/config`: Permission denied.

```
    sudo git init
    sudo git add  *
    sudo git commit -m "Add file"
    sudo git remote add origin https://github.com/gitsnippet/test-var.git
    sudo git push origin master
```

Now  github will ask username and password:

```
Username for 'https://github.com': xxxx
Password for 'https://gitsnippet@github.com': xxxx
```

How to make githtb read the username and password in `.netrc` when to git push files in `/var/www/html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the push as `sudo` means:

- a different `git config` setting: check `sudo git config credential.helper` (compared to `git config credential.helper`)
- a different `$HOME` (where sudo ls ~/.netrc might not exist)

Make sure those resources (`git config` and `.netrc`) exist in both environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo cp  $HOME/.netrc   /root/.netrc
```